# What is the difference between math.isnan ,numpy.isnan and pandas.isnull in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

A `NaN` of type decimal.Decimal causes:

1. math.isnan to return True
2. numpy.isnan to throw a TypeError exception.
3. pandas.isnull to return False

What is the difference between math.isnan, numpy.isnan and pandas.isnull?

Comment: _"does not cause numpy.isnan to evaluate to True"_ That's one way of putting it, though "raises an exception" seems more to the point.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't for me; as I said `np.isnan(decimal.Decimal('nan'))` raises an exception. What versions are you on?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I was thinking of pd.isnull, give me a moment to edit

Comment: None handles `Decimal` directly; so the result depends on how or whether they can convert it to something they do know about.  `numpy` is probably trying to make the object into its own float, and fails.  Pandas has, I think, a laundry list of things it checks, returning false if none match.

Answer (score 6):

The only difference between *math.isnan* and *numpy.isnan* is that

- **numpy.isnan** can **handle lists, arrays, tuples** whereas
- **math.isnan** can **ONLY handle single integers or floats.**

*However*, I suggest using *math.isnan* when you just want to check if a number is nan because

- **numpy** takes approximately **15MB of memory** when importing it while
- **math** takes only **0,2M of memory**

As for *pandas.isnull* it returns *True* not only for nan but also for None python types and as numpy it can handle every structure of numbers. However, it is even more "heavy" than numpy.