# Itertuples - avoid Null values

Tags: python, pandas

Supposing I have this dataframe (df):

```
  a     b     c
0 nan   Y     nan
1  23   N      3
2 nan   N      2
```

I need to loop to create an dictionary (in order to add to mongodb). Using this way, I can create the dictionary:

```
for i in df.itertuples():
  db.collection.insert_one({ 't':  getattr(i, 'a'),
    's':  getattr(i, 'b'),
    'v':  getattr(i, 'c')})
```

However, I would like to filter null values, and get only the following inputs:

```
  { 's':  'Y'},
  { 't':  23,'s': 'N', 'v': 3},
  { 's':  'N', 'v': 2}
```

Is there a directly way to accomplish this (I need to insert each dictionary separately on mongodb)?

Comment: Do you want a list of dictionaries?

Comment: I just need to add each dictionary inside db.collection.insert_one() function of mongodb

Comment: So the first interaction should be db.collection.insert_one({ 's':  'N'}) , the second db.collection.insert_one({ 't':  23,'s': 'N', 'v': 3}) and so on

Comment: Why is `{ 's':  'N'}` in 1st iteration? Shouldn't it be `{'s': 'Y'}`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You are correct.

Comment: Not familiar with mongoDB... Is `db.collection.insert_one` an inpalce function or does it return something that you want to use?

Comment: It is just a function that will add this dictionary into the database.

Comment: Thanks @Ch3steR, if you want to post your answer. It worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.itertuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) with `index` and `name`<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> parameter set to `None` and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and to check for `NaN` values you use [`pd.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html)<sup><sup>2</sup></sup>, [`math.nan`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan)<sup><sup>3</sup></sup> or [`np.isna`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html)<sup><sup>3</sup></sup>

```
for t in df.itertuples(index=None, name=None):
    db.collection.insert_one({k:v for k,v in zip(['t', 's', 'v'], t) if pd.notna(v)})
```

---

<sup><sup>1 You would get same out without setting `name` to `None`, if `name` is `None` the ouput of `list(df.itertuples(index=None))` is `[Pandas(a=nan, b='Y', c=nan), Pandas(a=23.0, b='N', c=3.0), Pandas(a=nan, b='N', c=2.0)]` each row is a NamedTuple. With `name` set to `None` output would be `[(nan, 'Y', nan), (23.0, 'N', 3.0), (nan, 'N', 2.0)]` each is just tuple.</sup></sup>

<sup><sup>2 `pd.isna` considers `None` as missing values `pd.isna(None)` gives `True` and `pd.isnull` is alias for `pd.isna`</sup></sup>

<sup><sup>3 `math.isnan` and `np.isnan` doesn't consider `None` as missing value `math.isnan` and `np.isnan` would raise `TypeError` and `math.isnan` works only with scalar values. Check out [`math.isnan` v/s `np.isnan` v/s `pd.isna`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57588107/what-is-the-difference-between-math-isnan-numpy-isnan-and-pandas-isnull-in-pyth)</sup></sup>

Answer (score 2):

Basically what I did was:

1. Renaming your columns (it seems like you want to do it in the end)
2. Converting each row to a dict, but first dropping `na` values

#### Here is the code:

```py
column_name_map = {
    "a": "t",
    "b": "s",
    "c": "v"
}
df_columns_renamed = df.rename(columns=column_name_map)

def row_to_dict(row):
    return row.dropna().to_dict()

df_columns_renamed.apply(row_to_dict, axis=1)
```

```py
# Result is:
0                         {'s': 'Y'}
1    {'t': 23.0, 's': 'N', 'v': 3.0}
2               {'s': 'N', 'v': 2.0}
```

Comment: Thanks Victor, I will have a look if this approach will work fine with MongoDB function.